# Exploitation of XSS vulnerability in search box where input is not reflected in URL

Tags: javascript, security, xss, penetration-testing

I have found an XSS vulnerability on a website where, upon user input in a search box, the webpage displays what the user is typing unfiltered/unsanitized. The user can input anything like `<script>alert(1)</script>`, or `<a href onmouseover=alert(1)>link</a>`, and the webpage runs the code. However, when the user searches this, the search is not reflected in the URL of the webpage. When the user searches something, the URL remains unchanged.. Is there a way that a vulnerability like this could be weaponized/exploited? This is for penetration testing and I have full authority/permission to do this. The webpage and HTML look like the following:

```
Results for
Search: this is what the user searched, this is unfiltered.
```

```
<Span>Results for</span>
" Search: "
<pre>this is what the user searched, this is unfiltered.</pre>
```

...

```
Results for
Search: [link]
```

```
<Span>Results for</span>
" Search: "
<pre>
    <a href onmouseover=alert(1)>link</a>
</pre>
```

Comment: I think it would depend on where the input goes. If it goes back to a server then it could be an issue, if it stays on the client, maybe not but it depends. Generally, script input by a user should not be running in either case. An exception would be in a code sandbox, the way code runs here on SO or CodePen, etc.

Comment: I've been working at this for a few days and I'm fairly new at this, but I'm fairly certain this does not go back to the server. Is it worth disclosing it with the company?

Comment: I'd say yes. The input should be sanitized/encoded so `<script>` would look like `&lt;script&gt;`, or some other encoding of angle brackets, which would be read as text instead of runnable code.